# How do i get to read the file if its in a docker container?

Tags: python, docker

i am trying to read a file in a docker container, precisly the etc/passwd, to make a list of old and new user, but i am stuck at making my function get the file in the docker container from my api

myoswrap is:
code.

```py
def readFileByLine( filename):
    try:
        command = f"cat {filename}"
        output = subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/docker", "exec", "userapi_cnt_ad", "sh", "-c", command])
        output_lines = output.decode("utf-8").splitlines()
        return output_lines
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return None
```

code for userapi

```py
@app.route('/users')
def route_getUsers():
    users = dom.getUserList()
    newUsers = []
    initialUsers = []
    for user in users:
        if dom.isInitialUser(user) == False:
            newUsers.append(user)
        else:
            initialUsers.append(user)
   
    return jsonify({"newUsers": newUsers, "initialUsers": initialUsers}), 200
```

userrepo is:

```py
import json
import docker
INITIAL_USERS = ['root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash', 'daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin', 'bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin', 'sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin', 'sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync', 'games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin', 'man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin', 'lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin', 'mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin',
                    'news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin', 'uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin', 'proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin', 'www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin', 'backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin', 'list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin', 'irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin', 'gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin', 'nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin', '_apt:x:100:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin']
```

userdomain is:

```py
def getUserList():
    users = []
    lines = myoswrap.readFileByLine('/etc/passwd')
    if lines is not None:  # Check if lines is not None
        for line in lines:
            users.append(line.split(':')[0])
    return users


def isInitialUser(username):
    if username in repo.INITIAL_USERS:
        return True

    return False
```

./startdocker is :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
docker container stop userapi_cnt_ad
docker container rm userapi_cnt_ad
docker image rm userapi_img_ad
docker volume rm ad_vol
docker volume create --name ad_vol --opt device=/mnt/share/ad-infra-tp-2-h-2024 --opt o=bind --opt type=none
docker build -t userapi_img_ad -f ./project/docker/Dockerfile .
docker run -d -p 15556:25556 --mount source=ad_vol,target=/mnt/app --name userapi_cnt_ad userapi_img_ad
```

my Dockerfile is:

```bash
FROM demers/python420w4a
COPY ./requirements.txt /
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt
WORKDIR /mnt/app/
CMD ["./run.sh", "./project/main/userapi.py", "25556"]
```

i tried docker.from_env(), but my postman get request said that it didnt recognize the from_env().

i also tried the

```py
output = subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/docker", "exec", "userapi_cnt_ad", "sh", "-c", command])
```

but it doesnt see the `/usr/bin/docker`

Comment: You probably don't want `docker exec` in most cases.  You need extremely privileged access to the host to be able to use it, and any changes it might make in a container will be lost as soon as the container exits.  I'd also expect it to be very unusual to edit `/etc/passwd` inside a container for similar reasons.  If the container process needs to run as an alternate user (usually to access a bind-mounted host directory) there's no requirement that the user "exist" in the `passwd` file.

Comment: Replace `/usr/bin/docker` with `docker`.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run this code in a container.  If the container is trying to inspect its own filesystem, you don't need anything special; just read `/etc/passwd` or any other file like normal.  You can't access the Docker socket without being given unrestricted root-level access over the entire host, and I'd consider whether there's another approach that might meet your needs first.

Comment: but thats what my userdomain is for no? @David Maze